# Same query different result in Oracle and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have 2 identical queries, but different results. For me the correct result is the Oracle, but I need execute this in SQL Server

SQL Server:

```
select power((1 + (power(1 + 0.05, 1 / 365)) - 1), 50) - 1

RESULTADO
0.00
```

ORACLE

```
select power(1+(power(1+0.05,1/365)-1),50)-1 from dual

RESULTADO
0,00670596912409796087090820980679344256
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Start with comparing `1/365`!

Comment: Addendum to the above comment: Floating point arithmetic is not exact, and can vary from database to database even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numbers in your SQL Server expression are [integer or decimal constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/constants-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).
You need to make some of them float constants, so that the result is float too.

You can do it like this:

```
select power((1 + (power(1 + 5E-2, 1 / 365E0)) - 1), 50) - 1
```

with the result:

```
0,00670596912411203
```

You can verify the type of expression using [SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/sql-variant-property-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
select SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( 1 / 365E0, 'BaseType'), 
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( 1 / 365E0, 'Precision'),
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( 1 / 365, 'BaseType'), 
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( 1 / 365, 'Precision'),
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( 0.05, 'BaseType'), 
       SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY ( 0.05, 'Precision')
```

Answer (score 2):

In the SQL case your using only two "0" after the "."

Try to use more then 2. should give you the same result after that.

:)

Comment: Like this: `select power((1.000000 + (power(1.000000 + 0.0500000, 1.00000 / 365.00000)) - 1.00000), 50.00000) - 1.00000`